# Access Base Class private members when implementing virtual function in derived class

Tags: c++

I am not very experienced with the OO side of C++ and I'm trying to port some code across and brush up my knowledge but I'm having an issue. I have a class defined like this:

```
class ExtendedKalmanFilter
{
private:

    double dt;


public:
    ExtendedKalmanFilter(int states);

    virtual VectorXd f(VectorXd x, VectorXd u);
    virtual MatrixXd F(VectorXd x);
    virtual VectorXd h(VectorXd x);
    virtual MatrixXd H(VectorXd x);

    ~ExtendedKalmanFilter();
};
```

I have another class which inherits `ExtendedKalmanFilter` and implements the virtual functions:

```
class KineticEnergyEKF : public ExtendedKalmanFilter {
public:
    KineticEnergyEKF(int nstates) : ExtendedKalmanFilter(nstates)
    {}


    VectorXd f(VectorXd x, VectorXd u)
    {
        this->dt = 1.0; //ERROR: Apparently I have no access to dt
    }
    MatrixXd F(VectorXd x);
    VectorXd h(VectorXd x);
    MatrixXd H(VectorXd x);
};
```

Visual Studio is showing that I can't access `dt`, but I can access the other functions defined in the `ExtendedKalmanFilter`. How do I access `dt`?

Comment: Make `dt` `protected` or add its `public`/`protected` access method in Base class.

Comment: Make `dt` accessible as `protected`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you inherit from a base class, all its private members are inaccessible to its derived children.

If you need to make them private to the outside world, but accessible to the derived classes, make such members `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `dt` protected (or public).

Private members of a class are not accessible outside that class (apart from by friend functions or classes), even by derived classes. Protected members are specifically designed to be members accessible by derived classes, but not the outside world.